# how to parse json array without "id"

Tags: android, json

Below is my code which parse JSON if I fetch "id".  If I don't give id then the JSON array will not show. How do i show JSON without id?

How do I parse JSONArray without "id" if I don't give id in JSON file then array will not show it is necessary to give "id" in JSON file???

this json array not show

```
 {
"status": 1,
"data": [
    {
        "title": "Elementary"
    },
    {
        "title": "Middle"
    },
    {
        "title": "High"
    },
    {
        "title": "Atypical"
    }
]
}
```

this json array will show

```
{
"status": 1,
"data": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "Elementary"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "Middle"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "title": "High"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "title": "Atypical"
    }
]
}
```

Code:

```
        JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject(str);

        status = json2.getString("status");
        if (status.equals("1")) {
        JSONArray school = json2.getJSONArray("data");
        for (int i = 0; i < school.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject object = school.getJSONObject(i);


                     //  Category_ID.add(Long.parseLong(object.getString("id")));
            Category_name.add(object.getString("title"));

        }
```

Comment: `object.getString("id")` ...

Comment: noi want to parse frist json file which have only "title" no "id"  thn how i will display that???

Comment: I'd recommend you to use some kind of JSON parser, eg. Jackson JSON or GSON libraries, to map those structures on POJO instances.

Comment: just tell me it is necessarry in android thave array if of each element in array??

Comment: i don't understand your last comment.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the id property here:

```
Category_ID.add(Long.parseLong(object.getString("id")));
```

When it is not there this will throw an exception.

Comment: i want to parse first json file which dont have "ID" attribute

Comment: if i remove this line Category_ID.add(Long.parseLong(object.getString("id"))); and parse first json file which dont have"id" then no value display it isnessary injosn to give id of each array element??

Comment: Right. You could also write some code that fetches the id only if it is provided in the JSON.

Comment: no my question is how to parsejson array if its dont have "id"

Comment: just tellme in android when parsing jsonarray it is necesary to give each object of array have id?

Comment: No, it is not necessary (if you don't access it). Why don't you try it out without this line?

Comment: bcoz in my code server dont give "id" just give me "title" only

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want your code to work for both JSON samples.

You can perform a check if "id" exists or not and then parse accordingly.

You can perform this check using the below code.

```
String id = object.optString("id"); 
//JSONObject.optString("id") will return id's value if it exists or else will return empty string.
if(!"".equals(id)){
       Category_ID.add(Long.parseLong(id));
       //this code will run only when your JSON contains id       
}
else 
{
     //this code will run when your JSON doesn't have id field.
     Category_ID.add();
}
```

Comment: u mean if no id exist then give default id??

Comment: that is my question in  my senario server dont give"id" in json file only give"title"

Comment: check the updated answer. I have given you a working solution which will work for both JSON samples with what i understood from your question. happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code while parsing your json:

```
if(object.has("id"))
{
Category_ID.add(Long.parseLong(object.getString("id")));
}
else
{
// add default id
}
```

hope this will work for you.

Comment: how ot add default id  // add default id
}

Comment: you can set your default id whatever you want.